# How to fragmentate a value in excel with another intersecting value

Tags: excel, function, split

I'll try to explain myself since I don't really know how to put in words this problem.

In Excel, I have to split a time value, which is the container of a whole, into different values (idealy in different rows); the split has to be done by the intersection of another value.

The idea would be as follows:
Original:

```
Name       Code          Start       End
Person 1   Container     10:00 am    4:00 pm 
Person 1   Break         12:30 pm    1:00 pm 
Person 2   Container      9:00 am    6:00 pm 
Person 2   Break         11:30 am   12:00 pm 
Person 2   Break          3:00 pm    3:30 pm
```

What I need:

```
Name       Code          Start        End
Person 1   Container     10:00 am     12:30 pm 
Person 1   Break         12:30 pm      1:00 pm 
Person 1   Container      1:00 pm      4:00 pm 
Person 2   Container      9:00 am     11:30 pm 
Person 2   Break         11:30 am     12:00 pm 
Person 2   Container     12:00 pm      3:00 pm 
Person 2   Break          3:00 pm      3:30 pm 
Person 2   Container      3:30 pm      6:00 pm
```

I've tried with formulas, but I don't get to make it work, since it has to create new rows. I also tried with pivot tables, but I haven't been able to figure it out; I'm not really good at coding, so I cannot say that I've tried my best there

If someone can give me an idea, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Assuming human entry, with the potential for overlapping breaks: how would you want to handle the situations where: 1) one break encapsulates the second; 2) where the second break starts in the middle of the first, but ends after the first one ends.

Comment: Are those values in one cell per line, or 4 cells per line?

Comment: @TimWilliams those are 4 cells per line. Thanks!

Comment: @Mistella For both scenarios, it should merge the breaks into one, considering the lowest start and the latest end. Thanks!

Comment: Can it be assumed that (1) all times occur on the same day (2) breaks never overlap  (3) breaks never extend outside of the "Container" start/end times ?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, all 3 scenarios occur as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below into a new module within the VBA editor ...

```
Public Sub SplitTime()
    Dim rngCells As Range, lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long, lngWriteRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim objDestSheet As Worksheet, objContainer As Scripting.Dictionary, objBreak As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim strPerson As String, strCode As String, strThisPerson As String, bFound As Boolean
    Dim x As Long, arrBreak(), lngContainerRow As Long, lngIndexToZero As Long, lngBreakRow As Long

    Dim tmStart, tmEnd, tmBreakStart, tmBreakEnd, tmThisBreakStart, tmThisBreakEnd

    Set objContainer = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set objBreak = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Set rngCells = Selection
    Set objDestSheet = Worksheets("Exploded")

    objDestSheet.Cells.Clear

    lngWriteRow = 1

    With rngCells
        ' Copy the header to the destination worksheet
        rngCells.EntireRow(1).Copy objDestSheet.Range("A1")

        ' Process each person first and foremost.
        ' We're going to assume that the data isn't sorted, it's safer.
        ' Capture the rows where the "container" row exist.
        ' In another dictionary, capture the "break" rows.
        For lngRow = 2 To .Rows.Count
            strPerson = .Cells(lngRow, 1)
            strCode = UCase(.Cells(lngRow, 2))

            If strCode = "CONTAINER" Then
                If Not objContainer.Exists(strPerson) Then
                    objContainer.Add strPerson, lngRow
                End If
            Else
                If Not objBreak.Exists(strPerson) Then
                    objBreak.Add strPerson, Array(lngRow)
                Else
                    arrBreak = objBreak.Item(strPerson)
                    ReDim Preserve arrBreak(UBound(arrBreak) + 1)
                    arrBreak(UBound(arrBreak)) = lngRow
                    objBreak.Item(strPerson) = arrBreak
                End If
            End If
        Next

        ' For each person, find the "break" rows and calculate accordingly.
        For i = 0 To objContainer.Count - 1
            strPerson = objContainer.Keys(i)
            lngContainerRow = CLng(objContainer.Item(strPerson))

            tmStart = TimeValue(.Cells(lngContainerRow, 3).Text)
            tmEnd = TimeValue(.Cells(lngContainerRow, 4).Text)

            lngWriteRow = lngWriteRow + 1

            objDestSheet.Cells(lngWriteRow, 1) = strPerson
            objDestSheet.Cells(lngWriteRow, 2) = "Container"
            objDestSheet.Cells(lngWriteRow, 3) = tmStart

            arrBreak = objBreak.Item(strPerson)

            Do While True
                tmBreakStart = ""
                bFound = False

                ' Get the lowest out of the breaks.
                For x = 0 To UBound(arrBreak)
                    lngBreakRow = CLng(arrBreak(x))

                    If lngBreakRow > 0 Then
                        bFound = True

                        tmThisBreakStart = TimeValue(.Cells(lngBreakRow, 3).Text)
                        tmThisBreakEnd = TimeValue(.Cells(lngBreakRow, 4).Text)

                        If tmBreakStart = "" Or tmThisBreakStart < tmBreakStart Then
                            lngIndexToZero = x

                            tmBreakStart = tmThisBreakStart
                            tmBreakEnd = tmThisBreakEnd
                        End If
                    End If
                Next

                If bFound Then
                    ' Finish off the current row.
                    objDestSheet.Cells(lngWriteRow, 4) = tmBreakStart

                    lngWriteRow = lngWriteRow + 1

                    ' Now write the next row with the breaks in it.
                    objDestSheet.Cells(lngWriteRow, 1) = strPerson
                    objDestSheet.Cells(lngWriteRow, 2) = "Break"
                    objDestSheet.Cells(lngWriteRow, 3) = tmBreakStart
                    objDestSheet.Cells(lngWriteRow, 4) = tmBreakEnd

                    lngWriteRow = lngWriteRow + 1

                    ' Now write the next row that will form the gap filler for the container.
                    objDestSheet.Cells(lngWriteRow, 1) = strPerson
                    objDestSheet.Cells(lngWriteRow, 2) = "Container"
                    objDestSheet.Cells(lngWriteRow, 3) = tmBreakEnd

                    arrBreak(lngIndexToZero) = 0
                Else
                    ' We've reached the end for that person.
                    objDestSheet.Cells(lngWriteRow, 4) = tmEnd

                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

... a few caveats.

1. Breaks cannot be end on end.  i.e. you can't have a break from 3pm to 4pm and then have a break directly after from 4pm to 5pm.  It doesn't make sense when you think about so if required, that break should be specified as 3pm to 5pm.  If you have end to end, it will break.
2. To make sure it works, be sure to format your time cells as time (`[$-409]h:mm AM/PM;@`)
3. The data doesn't need to be sorted, it will work regardless, in fact, you can see in the image below that I actually inserted the break for person 1 lower down and it still does produce the right result.
4. A person cannot start or end on a break.  Again, I figure that doesn't make sense anyway so haven't catered for it.

I don't think there's anything else you need to know.

To make it go, add a new worksheet into your book called **Exploded**, select your entire cell set and then run the macro.  The output will be on the "Exploded" worksheet.

[image: Selection]

I hope it works for you as it did for me.  If your data set is as basic as I'd expect it to be then it should go.